# Servlet não recebe o parâmetro da URL

Tags: java, servlet

Estou a tentar criar um sistema básico de recuperação de password. Cada utilizador tem um token armazenado na base de dados e quando tenta criar uma nova password, esta seria armazenada na mesma conta do valor do token apresentado na URL.

Exemplo, tenho este URL: http://localhost:8080/login/reset-password.jsp?token=cf76955642884215ab05ddfe20852aed com o token indicado como parâmetro.

O certo seria salvar a password onde o token tivesse este valor: "cf76955642884215ab05ddfe20852aed" porém quando tento inserir uma nova password, recebo a mensagem de que a password foi alterada, mas nada muda na base de dados.

Creio que seja algum problema com o request do parâmetro por URL no Servlet, porque quando insiro diretamente este valor no Sql query em reset_token, funciona perfeitamente.

Servlet:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String password = request.getParameter("password");
        String token = request.getParameter("token");



                ForgotPasswordHandler.UpdatePassword(password, token);

                String message = "Password changed!";
                request.setAttribute("message", message);
                request.getRequestDispatcher("reset-password.jsp?token=" + token).forward(request, response);   



    }
```

E o método da classe ForgotPasswordHandler.java que atualiza o valor da password na base de dados:

```
public static void UpdatePassword(String password, String token) throws SQLException {

            PreparedStatement ps = null;
            try
            {
                if (con == null){
                    System.out.println("Failed connection");
                } else {
                    ps = con.prepareStatement(
                        "UPDATE user SET password = ? WHERE reset_token = ?");

                    ps.setString(1,password);
                    ps.setString(2,token);

                    ps.executeUpdate();   

                   if (!con.getAutoCommit()) {
                      con.commit();
                   }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace(System.out);    
            } 
            finally {
                if (ps != null) {
                    ps.close();
                }
            }
```

Comment: Creio que o problema é que uma requisição POST pega os parâmetros do corpo (body), não da URL. Experimente passar o token no corpo da requisição.

Comment: @Piovezan Caramba, muito obrigada! Acabei por inserir o parâmetro da URL num hidden input e deu certo! Muito obrigada mesmo!